# Cast string to float is not supported in Linear Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, linearmodels

I keep getting this error in my linear model:

> Cast string to float is not supported

Specifically, the error is on this line:

```
results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), steps=1)
```

If it helps, here's the stack trace:

```
 File "tensorflowtest.py", line 164, in <module>
    m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=int(100))
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 475, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 333, in fit
    max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 662, in _train_model
    train_op, loss_op = self._get_train_ops(features, targets)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 963, in _get_train_ops
    _, loss, train_op = self._call_model_fn(features, targets, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 944, in _call_model_fn
    return self._model_fn(features, targets, mode=mode, params=self.params)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 220, in _linear_classifier_model_fn
    loss = loss_fn(logits, targets)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/linear.py", line 141, in _log_loss_with_two_classes
    logits, math_ops.to_float(target))
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 661, in to_float
    return cast(x, dtypes.float32, name=name)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 616, in cast
    return gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 419, in cast
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Cast", x=x, DstT=DstT, name=name)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 749, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2380, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/computer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1298, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Cast string to float is not supported
         [[Node: ToFloat = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_STRING, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_1)]]
```

The model is an adaptation of the tutorial from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide/index.html) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py). The tutorial code does run, so it's not a problem with my TensorFlow installation.

The input CSV is data in the form of many binary categorical columns (`yes`/`no`). Initially, I represented the data in each column as 0's and 1's, but I get the same error when I change it to `y`s and `n`s.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 20):

I had the exact same problem, you need to make sure that the input data you are feeding the model is in the right format. ( not just the features but also the label column)

My problem was that i was not skipping the first row in the data file, so i was trying to convert the titles to float format.Something as simple as adding

```
skiprows=1
```

When reading the csv:

```
df_test = pd.read_csv(test_file, names=COLUMNS_TEST, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, engine="python")
```

I would recommend you to check:

```
df_test.dtypes
```

You should get something like

```
Feature1      int64
Feature2      int64
Feature3      int64
Feature4      object
Feature5      object
Feature6      float64
dtype: object
```

If you are not getting the correct dtype then the model.fit is going to fail

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a data type issue, but it is NOT because you included the row of column names. Those are most often required. This error was most likely due to interpreting a categorical column as a numerical one. E.g. some features are objects.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you probably had indicated the feature like a **real**  type but in your data frame is still **string** or when set in tf.constant you didn't cast to correct type.

Confirm the types of your columns. You can check just type (df is your dataframe):

```
df.info()
```

And you can see all columns and types, some like that:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 178932 entries, 0 to 178931
Data columns (total 64 columns):
d_prcp                      178932 non-null float64
d_stn                       178932 non-null int64
ws_lat                      178932 non-null float64
ws_lon                      178932 non-null float64
d_year                      178932 non-null int64
d_temp                      178932 non-null float64
...
```

You can use this bellow function  in order to convert your data in correct type in **tensorflow**. (this code is from a repo *google/training-data-analyst*: [link here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/tensorflow/b_tflearn.ipynb))

```
def make_input_fn(df):
  def pandas_to_tf(pdcol):
    # convert the pandas column values to float
    t = tf.constant(pdcol.astype('float32').values)
    # take the column which is of shape (N) and make it (N, 1)
    return tf.expand_dims(t, -1)

  def input_fn():
    # create features, columns
    features = {k: pandas_to_tf(df[k]) for k in FEATURES}
    labels = tf.constant(df[TARGET].values)
    return features, labels
  return input_fn

def make_feature_cols():
  input_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
  return input_columns
```

Comment: Please leave a comment before a down vote. The line  t = tf.constant(pdcol.astype('float32').values) can solve the main problem of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't literally cast a string to a number, particularly "y","n" to 1.0/0.0.

If you have numeric strings (e.g. "0") you could try [`tf.string_to_number(..)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#string_to_number)

Comment: link is not working. This is the new one `https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/strings/to_number`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I tried replicating the steps on a different data-set for practice.

SIMPLE TO FIX, just use the following code to change the data type of your TARGET COLUMN to int,

`df["target_column_name"] = df["target_column_name"].astype(str).astype(int)`

Also, you need to do it at the starting, when the target column is inside your data-file initially.

Answer (score 1):

I am using W10, Python3 and Tensorflow 1.9

The source of the error in my code was in the feature definition. I had a boolean feature with a `default_value` of -1 like this:

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list( 
    key='partial_funding_indicator', vocabulary_list=['True', 'False'],
    dtype=tf.string, **default_value=-1**, num_oov_buckets=None)
```

The issue did not arise when the `default_value` was changed to `0`:

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key='partial_funding_indicator', vocabulary_list=['True', 'False'],
    dtype=tf.string, **default_value=0**, num_oov_buckets=None)
```

`default_value` is the integer ID value to return for out-of-vocabulary feature values.  For example, in a list/file of value like `['True', 'False']` to make `default_value == True`, it would be `default_value=0`; the list index.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are probably in string forms and they need to be numeric (1 and 0 only for this specific tutorial)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? You mean the clases in the input or the classes in the model?

Comment: By classes here I mean the labels, this example only works for a binary classification problem, the labels has to be specifically numeric and 0 or 1 only

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error is because `m.evaluate` is somehow empty.

Since you load your data from csv file, it is very likely that your data was stored as string instead of float or int inside the array. I suggest you check it manually to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you're using `tf.cast()` to convert a string to number, but you cannot do this. Replace it with [tf.strings.to_number()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/to_number):

```
tf.strings.to_number(x, out_type=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's a header on the file you've imported to work on. The header is of the type `string` and the rest of the rows are `int64` or `float64`. While the types are variant in a column they are typed as `object` . You can check and make sure the this is the problem with this code:

```
df_test.dtypes
```

To solve this you can simply delete the header row from your CSV before importing it to pyhton. Just remember that if you drop that row after importing it will not work and the data types won't change!

Answer (score 0):

The other way is using

df = df.astype({'COL1': 'float64', 'COL2': 'float64'})

for a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Some times the reason is ***that your feeding data is not in the string format*** and that is example of **WRONGE** data

```
,0
' or x = 1 , 1, 0,1
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE(1 = 1, 1, 0 = 0,0),1
```

Try to clean your dataset first and honestly this worked with me in my graduation project dataset

Comment: You should read the question carefully. The error says `Cast string to float is not supported` means the data is actually a `string` but it don't know how to cast that string data into a `float`. Please refer [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @nobleknight I know bro, I give him solution for the same error happened to me with same situation and what I did to solve this error only, the data may be string but the problem with extracting this data.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate answer is, that you need to change your `df_test`'s format to the same format as your `df_train` at the very beginning.

For example,

```py
df_train.replace({'yes':1,'no':0}, inplace = True)
    
df_test.replace({'yes':1,'no':0}, inplace = True)
```