# Machine learning : Cast string to float is not supported in sequential model using python language

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, sequential

I try to predict the class but it shows the error:

```
Cast string to float is not supported.
```

I used `model.predict_classes` that is deprecated now. So I used `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`, but I get the same error.

I use to look at some other similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186722/cast-string-to-float-is-not-supported-in-linear-model), but doesn't work for me. I am using python language and code at colab.

Comment: The error is clear: You have some strings in your input which is the `csv` file. Check it for strings. It may be the headers that you didn't exclude it while reading.

Comment: print `xnew.dtypes` and iadd its output to the question to see if all values are in the expected format.

Comment: Here is the xnew.dtypes result
xnew.dtypes
ADDRESS    object
OPCODE     object
dtype: object

Comment: Should the ADDRESS column values be integer?

Comment: integer or  hexadecimal

Comment: `xnew.dtypes` print `object` the type of ADDRESS. So check your book2.csv file for values of the address column. It have null values or string values.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I change the whole data frame to float and it starts working.