# Why is tensorflow giving a bizarre error that I could not troubleshoot

Tags: python, tensorflow

So i made my first tensorflow model and i got this error

I am sure that something is wrong with my version of tensorflow, because this almost the exact same as the example in the official docs

```
2023-07-18 22:18:33.588749: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py:32: categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list (from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Keras preprocessing layers instead, either directly or via the `tf.keras.utils.FeatureSpace` utility. Each of `tf.feature_column.*` has a functional equivalent in `tf.keras.layers` for feature preprocessing when training a Keras model.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py:35: numeric_column (from tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column_v2) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Keras preprocessing layers instead, either directly or via the `tf.keras.utils.FeatureSpace` utility. Each of `tf.feature_column.*` has a functional equivalent in `tf.keras.layers` for feature preprocessing when training a Keras model.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py:49: LinearClassifierV2.__init__ (from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.linear) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/head/head_utils.py:54: BinaryClassHead.__init__ (from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.head.binary_class_head) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py:944: Estimator.__init__ (from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.estimator) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1844: RunConfig.__init__ (from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.run_config) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /var/folders/wy/hbvv3yzs02vdrrsb_wfrwy3r0000gn/T/tmp07bjbpjq
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/optimizers/legacy/ftrl.py:173: calling Constant.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.init_ops) with dtype is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/model_fn.py:250: EstimatorSpec.__new__ (from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.model_fn) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1416: NanTensorHook.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1419: LoggingTensorHook.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py:232: SecondOrStepTimer.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1456: CheckpointSaverHook.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py:579: StepCounterHook.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py:586: SummarySaverHook.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
2023-07-18 22:18:39.053940: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:375] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py:1455: SessionRunArgs.__new__ (from tensorflow.python.training.session_run_hook) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py:1454: SessionRunContext.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.session_run_hook) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.keras instead.
2023-07-18 22:18:40.073267: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1805] OP_REQUIRES failed at cast_op.cc:121 : UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1379, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1362, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1455, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/age/Cast}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py", line 50, in <module>
    model.train(train_model)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 360, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1219, in _train_model_default
    return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1535, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 778, in run
    return self._sess.run(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1307, in run
    return self._sess.run(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1397, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1464, in run
    outputs = _WrappedSession.run(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1228, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 969, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1192, in _run
    results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1372, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1398, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/age/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py", line 50, in <module>
      model.train(train_model)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 360, in train
      loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model
      return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1216, in _train_model_default
      estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1176, in _call_model_fn
      model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 934, in _model_fn
      return _linear_model_fn_v2(
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 662, in _linear_model_fn_v2
      logits, trainable_variables = _linear_model_fn_builder_v2(
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 599, in _linear_model_fn_builder_v2
      logits = linear_model(features)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 569, in __call__
      return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 838, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1668, in call
      return self.layer(features)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 838, in __call__
      outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1489, in call
      for column in self._feature_columns:
    File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1496, in call
      weighted_sum = fc_v2._create_weighted_sum(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
Node: 'linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/age/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/age/Cast}}]]

Original stack trace for 'linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/age/Cast':
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Documents/ML.py", line 50, in <module>
    model.train(train_model)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 360, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1188, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1216, in _train_model_default
    estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1176, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 934, in _model_fn
    return _linear_model_fn_v2(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 662, in _linear_model_fn_v2
    logits, trainable_variables = _linear_model_fn_builder_v2(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 599, in _linear_model_fn_builder_v2
    logits = linear_model(features)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 569, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 838, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1668, in call
    return self.layer(features)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer_v1.py", line 838, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1489, in call
    for column in self._feature_columns:
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 454, in for_stmt
    for_fn(iter_, extra_test, body, get_state, set_state, symbol_names, opts)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 505, in _py_for_stmt
    body(target)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 471, in protected_body
    original_body(protected_iter)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 1496, in call
    weighted_sum = fc_v2._create_weighted_sum(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2297, in _create_weighted_sum
    return _create_dense_column_weighted_sum(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2307, in _create_dense_column_weighted_sum
    tensor = column.get_dense_tensor(transformation_cache, state_manager)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2756, in get_dense_tensor
    return transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2516, in get
    transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2729, in transform_feature
    return self._transform_input_tensor(input_tensor)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_v2.py", line 2704, in _transform_input_tensor
    return math_ops.cast(input_tensor, dtypes.float32)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 150, in error_handler
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 1176, in op_dispatch_handler
    return dispatch_target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1018, in cast
    x = gen_math_ops.cast(x, base_type, name=name)
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 2014, in cast
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 795, in _apply_op_helper
    op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
  File "/Users/anirudhmenon/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3381, in _create_op_internal
    ret = Operation.from_node_def(
```

I could not find any solutions on the web

Edit: This is the code, a slightly modefied version of the official sample code on the tensorflow docs.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib

import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc

import tensorflow as tf

# Load dataset.
dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
dfeval = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv') 

# Convert 'age' column to string type
dftrain['age'] = dftrain['age'].astype(str)
dfeval['age'] = dfeval['age'].astype(str)

y_train = dftrain.pop('survived')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('survived')

clear_output()
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sex', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class', 'deck',
                       'embark_town', 'alone']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['age', 'fare']

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    unique = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, unique))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))


def make_input_fn(label_df, data_df, num_epochs=30, batch_size=627):
    def input_fn():
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
        ds = ds.shuffle(1000)
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
        return ds
    return input_fn

train_model = make_input_fn(y_train, dftrain)
evaluate_model = make_input_fn(y_eval, dfeval, num_epochs=1)

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
model.train(train_model)
stats = model.evaluate(evaluate_model)
clear_output()
print(stats['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast string to float is not supported in Linear Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186722/cast-string-to-float-is-not-supported-in-linear-model)

Comment: You did not include any code, so not sure what you expect as an answer.

Comment: Hi @Anirudh Menon, The code you have mentioned is only compatible with Tensorflow v1 and most of the used APIs are deprecated (feature_column, tf.estimator) as mentioned in this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear). Please refer to this [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#mixed_data_types) where similar classification model with the same dataset already explained.